# how package text files into vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

my extension is using handlebars to apply substitution variables to a text template. Where can I store the template text in the extension?

I am currently storing the templates as strings in the extension.ts file. Would rather use a folder that stores the template files and include that folder in the vsce package.

Comment: You can store them wherever you like in your extension directory, as long as you don't put them into `.vscodeignore`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To store, package and access files, you can do the following:

1. create a sub-folder in your extension root (same level as `package.json`), let's give it a name `resources`.
2. Place a `file.txt` in that folder
3. The file will get packaged as long as you do not list it in `.vscodeignore` (as mentioned by Gama11)
4. Access it using the `context.asAbsolutePath(...)` API

Example:

```js
import * as path from 'path';
import * as fs from 'fs';

export function activate(context: ExtensionContext) {
    let fullFilePath = context.asAbsolutePath(path.join('resources', 'file.txt'));
    fs.readFile(fullFilePath, (err, data) => { ... });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Note that 'templates' should read resources in 5th line.